# How to add onload to HTML without it being part of the body tag?

Tags: javascript, html, joomla3.0

I was told to add a  tag being generated in Joomla. I just need to add the onload=... between the body tags. Is there a way to add the onload=... by itself or must it be part of the  tag? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, and you need to trigger some JavaScript to run after the document is ready without editing the body tag itself, you could add it as follows:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        // Your code
    }
</script>
```

Notice the lack of "$". In Joomla, avoid using $ to reference jQuery to prevent conflicts with other JS tools.

If I've completely missed the mark, please clarify in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the event handler with JavaScript.

```
<script>
    addEventListener('load', yourFunction);

    function yourFunction(event) {
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `<script>` tag to the header of the page, you can then add an event listener for the page load. Or a better option is to prevent render blocking code and add the `<script>` tag to the bottom of the page and have it run right away, since the page is already loaded.

**Render Blocking Method**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('load',pageLoaded,false);
      function pageLoaded(e) { console.log('Loaded'); }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Non Render Blocking**

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- All The Body Content -->
    <script>
      (function() {
        console.log('Loaded');
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```